# Create multiple div using data from array using for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I want to assign array elements to multiple divs which also have image tag in them using for loop.
Array consists of image paths.

```
var img_list = ["one.png", "two.png", "three.png", "four.png"];
```

By using above array I have to create below HTML Structure. All divs should be inside "outer" div with a data-slide attribute which is without ".png".

```
<div id="outer">
  <div class="slide" data-slide="one"><img src="Images/one.png" /></div>
  <div class="slide" data-slide="two"><img src="Images/two.png" /></div>
  <div class="slide" data-slide="three"><img src="Images/three.png" /></div>
  <div class="slide" data-slide="four"><img src="Images/four.png" /></div>
</div>
```

This is what I wrote:

```
for (var i=0; i < img_list.length; i++){
    var container = document.getElementById("outer").innerHTML;
    var new_card = "<div class=\"slide\" data-slide=\'" + img_list[i] + "\'><img src=\'Images/" + img_list[i] + "\' /></div>";
    document.getElementById("outer").innerHTML = new_card;
}
```

But it is only showing the last image.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code at the question overwrites the `.innerHTML` within the `for` loop by setting `.innerHTML` to `new_card` at every iteration of the array. You can substitute `.insertAdjacentHTML()` for setting `.innerHTML`. Also, substitute `const` for `var` to prevent `new_card` from being defined globally. Include `alt` attribute at `<img>` element. You can `.split()` `img_list[0]` at dot character `.`, `.shift()` the resulting array to get word before `.` in the string `img_list[i]` to set `data-*` attribute value.

```js
const img_list = ["one.png", "two.png", "three.png", "four.png"];

for (let i = 0, container = document.getElementById("outer"); i < img_list.length; i++) {
  const src = img_list[i];
  const data = src.split(".").shift();
  const new_card = `<div class="slide" data-slide="${data}"><img src="Images/${src}" alt="${data}"/></div>`;
  container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", new_card);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Each time your for loop runs, it is replacing the html element within the "outer" div with the current img html.

In order to have it append you can simply change
`document.getElementById("outer").innerHTML = new_card;`
to
`document.getElementById("outer").innerHTML += new_card;` so that the element is appended rather than overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the `innerHTML` you need to add to it. And use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for creating html strings

```js
var img_list = ["one.png", "two.png", "three.png", "four.png"];
const outer = document.getElementById('outer')
img_list.forEach(img => {
  outer.innerHTML += `<div class="slider" data-slide="${img.split('.')[0]}"><img src="Images/${img}" /></div>` 
})
console.log(outer.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="outer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tony7931, please replace the last line of for loop with below code:

```
document.getElementById("outer").innerHTML += new_card;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can declare your variables outside of the loop and reuse them. This is more efficient.
2. const and let are preferable to var. You only need to set container once so it can be const. new_card should be let since you need to assign it more than once.
3. You can also use template string so you don't need all the back slashes.
4. using forEach will make the code cleaner:

```js
const img_list = ["one.png", "two.png", "three.png", "four.png"];
const container = document.getElementById("outer")
let new_card;
img_list.forEach(i => {
    new_card = `<div class=slide data-slide='${i.split(".")[0]}'><img src='Images/${i}'></div>`
    container.innerHTML += new_card;
})
```

```html
    <div id="outer">
    </div>
```

Alternately, using reduce:

```js
const img_list = ["one.png", "two.png", "three.png", "four.png"];
const container = document.getElementById("outer")
const reducer = (a, i) => a + `<div class=slide data-slide='${i.split(".")[0]}'><img src='Images/${i}'></div>`
container.innerHTML = img_list.reduce(reducer, '')
```

```html
    <div id="outer">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there but, every time you are overriding the slider div.

You just have to add `+` at assignments section. like below.

`document.getElementById("outer").innerHTML += new_card;`

Here is the full example:

```js
var img_list = ["one.png", "two.png", "three.png", "four.png"];

for (var i=0; i < img_list.length; i++){
    var container = document.getElementById("outer").innerHTML;
    var new_card = "<div class=\"slide\" data-slide=\'" + img_list[i].split('.')[0] + "\'><img src=\'Images/" + img_list[i] + "\' /></div>";
    document.getElementById("outer").innerHTML += new_card;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method of array and [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to get the required result.

> The **map()** method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

---

**Demo**

```js
const img_list = ["one.png", "two.png", "three.png", "four.png"];

let result = img_list.map((v, i) => `<div class="slide" data-slide="${v.split(".")[0]}"><img src="Images/${v}"/>${i+1}</div>`).join('');

document.getElementById('outer').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="outer"></div>
```